# Where can digital AD&D 1e books be bought?

Tags: adnd-1e, books, online-resources

I am looking to join an AD&D 1e campaign, and I need the sourcebooks, too.
Where online I can buy digital AD&D 1e books?

Comment: I've removed the second question (the site properly handles only one question per question post), but the answer can be found in another question we already have: [Where can I find other RPG players?](//rpg.stackexchange.com/q/1232)

Answer (score 6):

All legal D&D PDFs can be downloaded at the [Dungeon Master's Guild](http://www.dmsguild.com/browse.php?filters=0_0_0_0_0_45346_0_0).

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for free or inexpensive AD&D 1e-compatible material, you may also want to consider retroclones, such as [OSRIC](http://www.knights-n-knaves.com/osric/).

Comment: This doesn't answer where to find AD&D 1e books, and comes across as a forum discussion post. You might want to expand and answer the question directly.

Comment: @doppelgreener I had originally had a sentence about using OSRIC as a spell reference for an AD&D1 game, but it made the answer seem forced.